# HAProxy Combined Acls

Tags: haproxy

I'm trying to make a combined acl in the haproxy config.
Is this kind of thing possible ??

```
  acl bare-dom1 hdr(host) -m reg -i domain1.org(:[0-9]+)?$
  acl bare-dom2 hdr(host) -m reg -i domain2.org(:[0-9]+)?$
  acl bare-dom3 hdr(host) -m reg -i domain3.org(:[0-9]+)?$
  acl needs-www (bare-dom1 || bare-dom2 || bare-dom3)
```

Unfortunately from looking around so far, I don't see a way to do it.
Yeah sure I could add the big OR to the place where I'm going to use it, but maybe I will have 20 domains later, and if I'm gonna use it in multiple places its going to get ugly.

Answer (score 2):

You can repeat an ACL with the same name multiple times, they will be combined as with 'OR' operator.

Example:

```
acl bare-dom hdr(host) -m reg -i domain1.org(:[0-9]+)?$
acl bare-dom hdr(host) -m reg -i domain2.org(:[0-9]+)?$
acl bare-dom hdr(host) -m reg -i domain3.org(:[0-9]+)?$
use_backend backend bare-dom
```

I don't think it is possible to combine named ACLs into another named ACL.

Comment: Thanks, seems good, but the last line of setting a new acl, just based on another acl still doesn't seem to work.   Unless anyone has other ideas, I can just use needs-www as the main variable in the first 3 lines.  Of course the disadvantage of this, is that I cannot use bare-dom1 bare-dom2 etc in future conditions.  Would be awesome if haproxy just implemented this "new acl from existing acls" feature alonng with the use of full logical operators.

Comment: @blissweb You are right, I copied the last line without thinking. I don't think it is currently possible to combine named ACLs into another named ACL